# Error when joining objects: "Apply all rotations before join objects"

Tags: grease-pencil

[image: Text]
I think I'm the first person in the world to get this error. I'm not rotating anything, I am only trying to merge objects. What's up with this error?

Comment: Please explain step by step what actions you've taken that resulted in this error and include a screenshot of your project. Presumably you are trying to join grease pencil objects?

Comment: It's just a bunch of grease pencils: [PHOTO1](https://i.ibb.co/55mQT4R/1.jpg) No keyframes on the dope sheet/timeline. **Step 1:** Select all of Grease Pencil layers (not selecting camera) [PHOTO2](https://i.ibb.co/0jhfCBp/2.jpg) **Step 2:** Object>Join (I also tried Ctrl+J) [PHOTO3](https://i.ibb.co/MNs5ZZV/3.jpg) **3:** ERROR. [PHOTO4](https://i.ibb.co/Sc5LsV4/4.jpg) I think it is because I have 100s of layers. Since it says apply all rotations, I tried rotating & then joining too: [PHOTO5](https://i.ibb.co/SfH2ybf/5.jpg)

Comment: I am commenting again with a version of the blend file if you feel like experimenting with it. It is a large file because there are hundreds of grease pencil objects that wont join: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HL9nGElS5zG6EhN56qtC2N8Dww20gyeH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The error indicates that you have rotated at least one of the grease pencil objects you are trying to join. Have you tried applying its rotation with *Ctrl + A > Rotation* before you attempt to join them?

Comment: [PHOTO6](https://i.ibb.co/VjwnCPy/photo6.jpg) Wow, what a terrible mess this has made [PHOTO7](https://i.ibb.co/1fr93mM/photo7.jpg). But this does in fact join the objects. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Answer was provided by dev Robert Gützkow:
**Step 1:** Select all objects, *Ctrl* + *A*, > *Rotation*
[image]
There will be no visible changes after this step.

**Step 2:** Attempt to join again *Ctrl* + *J*
[image]
Grease pencil objects are now joined. Expect unwanted graphical changes.